# tf tutorial start_demo.launch wtf

Tags: ros, tutorials, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
 <launch>
  <!-- Turtlesim Node-->

      <node pkg="turtlesim" type="turtlesim_node" name="sim"/>
      <node pkg="turtlesim" type="turtle_teleop_key" name="teleop" output="screen"/>
    
        
        <param name="turtle" type="string" value="turtle1" />
      </node>
        
        <param name="turtle" type="string" value="turtle2" /> 
      </node>
    
    </launch>
```

What is wrong with this launch file? and I don't mean the spacing, I have reformatted it a bunch and already know xml formatting has to be spaced right and all that. it's got to be the code itself, which is directly from http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20tf%20broadcaster%20%28Python%29 tf tutorial and I'm surprised I only saw one unanswered question about this issue, but I assume it's because the others know how to make xml syntax correct and just moved on.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/270919/tf-tutorial-start_demo.launch-wtf/) by [moonspacedancer](https://answers.ros.org/users/31680/moonspacedancer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 123 on 2017-09-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You're missing a lot of the content of the launch file in the tutorial. In particular two of the four node elements (and only have the close elements). Make sure you're copying the whole file.

Copying from the tutorial it looks like this:

```
  <launch>
    <!-- Turtlesim Node-->
    <node pkg="turtlesim" type="turtlesim_node" name="sim"/>
    <node pkg="turtlesim" type="turtle_teleop_key" name="teleop" output="screen"/>

    <node name="turtle1_tf_broadcaster" pkg="learning_tf" type="turtle_tf_broadcaster.py" respawn="false" output="screen" >
      <param name="turtle" type="string" value="turtle1" />
    </node>
    <node name="turtle2_tf_broadcaster" pkg="learning_tf" type="turtle_tf_broadcaster.py" respawn="false" output="screen" >
      <param name="turtle" type="string" value="turtle2" /> 
    </node>

  </launch>
```

Edit: here's how it renders:
[image: image description]

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2017-09-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [moonspacedancer](https://answers.ros.org/users/31680/moonspacedancer/) on 2017-09-14**:
well thats weird. mine doesn't include all that... you copied this from the same page I linked? maybe its chromium.. it does sometimes do weird things. so strange though.. that was copied from right under '2. Running the Broadcaster'? @tfoote ? thank you